# How to change background-color of primeng p-tabview header on active state?

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<div class="task-details">
<p-tabView>
 <p-tabPanel header="Task Details" [selected]="false" id="taskd"></p-tabPanel>
<p-tabPanel header="LOGS" [selected]="false" id="logs" >
  <div class="logdetailsdata">
  </div>
</p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
</div>
```

Header background color should change to rgb(0,30,255) on active state. How can it be changed?

Comment: I want to override the existing css background-color

Comment: `.ui-tabview-nav li.ui-state-active { background-color: rgb(0,30,355) !important; }`

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090206/chris-w .

Comment: I forgot to put !important in my CSS so that it dint work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hover` in CSS:

```
hover { 
  background-color: rgb(0,30,255);
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Actually, this is related to prime ng tabview not a generalized css class/id. This is not the correct solution for this.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question then